# How to debug setting up localhost local websites for development on Mac

Tags: macos, apache, localhost

I have been using Mamp Pro, but I removed it and want to use built in apache /  mysql on my mac for local development. Mamp has been fine but I feel it is restricting my knowledge and not given me much value-added in terms of keeping config separate from my machine settings.

However, I've followed various tutorials for setting up localhost and now http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1 doesn't work in the browser. I've been messing about with it on and off and forgotten what I've changed.

What steps can I take to reset everything back to factory apache settings and start over or debug my existing set up to find out what is going wrong?

Comment: Please describe your Problem more in detail. I suggest to go step by step. So before we're dealing with php / mysql i would check the Apache itself is working properly. 
What error do you get exactly when you try `http://localhost`. Check `/var/log/apache2/access_log` and `/var/log/apache2/error_log`

Comment: checking the logs should be helpful thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what exactly you might've changed, although the first step would be to copy the default `php.ini` over the one you likely would've modified:

```
$ mv /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

also look in `/etc/apache2` for default `.conf` files and do the same over the modified versions.

Comment: yes first issue is with apache and accessing an index.html file in a directory somewhere via the browser